# Converting Strings to Reals in a List

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion, streams

I am new to Mathematica and working with streamed data:

```
 str = OpenRead["https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2019-03.csv"]
memory=ReadList[str, Record,500];
```

I'd now like to convert the records from the streamed file into a new list, by converting all numbers to reals. It seems like the default storage method of the data is string for any entry. Correct? In particular, I would need to convert the following variables to reals: *Vendor ID, passenger_count, trip_distance, RatecodeID, PULocationID, DOLocationID, payment_type, fare_amount, extra, mta_tax, tip_amount, tolls_amount, improvement_surcharge, total_amount and congestion_surcharge*.

Unfortunately, I am struggling to do this - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your dataset is 700MB, much too big for tests. Please make a small test data set.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the hint. I have updated my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a test, I only read the first 5 records:

```
str = OpenRead[
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2019-03.csv"]
mem = ReadList[str, Record, 5];
```

Now we extract the header and the data and split them into the corresponding table elements:

```
header = StringSplit[mem[[1]], ","]
dat = StringSplit[Rest[mem], ","];
```

The rows of `dat` consists of strings that represent a mixture of numbers and strings. To transform the strings representing numbers we need to to pick out the corresponding columns:

```
(dat[[All, #]] = ToExpression[dat[[All, #]]]) & /@ {1, 4 ;; 6, 8 ;;}
```

To get the final table we prepend the header to the data:

```
PrependTo[dat, header]
```

[image]

If in addition you want also to change the date strings into numeric lists, you may say:

```
dat[[All, 2]] = DateList /@ dat[[All, 2]]
dat[[All, 3]] = DateList /@ dat[[All, 3]]
```

Or with `DateObject`:

```
  dat[[All, 2]] = DateObject /@ dat[[All, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! One last question: Instead of a DateList object, I would need to convert my date strings into a DateObject. Simply exchanging DateList with DateObject /@dat[[All, 3]] in your code yields an error message. Any hint on a different approach? Thanks again!

Comment: Should work with `DateObject` too (at least in version 12.1. I made an add in my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The third argument according to [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) is for:

> reads only the first n objects of the specified types.

This code will run on 3 record (first row is column):

```
records = ReadList[str, Record, 3];
```

the output is a list of strings, use `SemanticImportString` to convert strings to their data types (Reals, ...).`SemanticImportString` needs a string with `\n` as the record separator.

Use `StringRiffle` to concatenate records with `\n` in between.

```
SemanticImportString[#, Automatic, "Rows", Delimiters -> ","] &@
 StringJoin@StringRiffle[records, "\n"]
```

Output:

[image]

Using `"Dataset"` form instead of `"Rows"`:

```
SemanticImportString[#, Automatic, "Dataset", Delimiters -> ","] &@
 StringJoin@StringRiffle[records, "\n"]
```

Output:

[image]

The output is a list of records with different types (String, Reals, ...). See `SemanticImport` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) to read more about other output forms.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I have just checked and it seems that all elements of the list are strings by default already, correct? How would I now go about converting all the list elements that are numbers to reals? These would be the following columns: Vendor ID, passenger_count, trip_distance, RatecodeID, PULocationID, DOLocationID, payment_type, fare_amount, extra, mta_tax, tip_amount, tolls_amount, improvement_surcharge, total_amount and congestion_surcharge.